# C# Excel Addin - Alter custom task pane text box from ThisAddIn.cs

Tags: c#, event-handling, excel-addins

Is there a way to access controls from a custom task pane when creating event handlers in the "ThisAddIn.cs" file?

I want to allow the user to either enter a cell reference manually, or just click on a cell and have that reference value show up in the text box on my user control. I'm unsure how to actually access my controls within an event handler.

I would have thought it'd have been as simple as just

```
myUserControl.txtMyTextBox.Text = active cell
```

I've been googling, but feel I may not be using the correct terminology.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is some actual code. My wording is never the best.

```
namespace MyExcelAddin
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private userCtrl myUserCtrl = new userCtrl();
        public Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane tskPaneUsers;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
               tskPaneUsers = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(userCtrl, "My Control");
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void ThisAddIn_SheetSelectionChange(object sender, Excel.Range Target)
        {
            //This is where I want to access my textbox inside my usercontrol. 
            // Is it out of scope?  
        }

 private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
            Application.SheetSelectionChange += new Excel.AppEvents_SheetSelectionChangeEventHandler(ThisAddIn_SheetSelectionChange);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current excel components via the `Excel.Application` object.
You can initialize it during your add-in loading process as `ThisAddIn.Application` property.

Once you have access to the `Excel.Application` object, you can use it to reference the active sheet and cell similar calls to

```
ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell.Row
ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveCell.Column
```

you can also convert the `Row` and `Column` properties to `String` and combine them into your TextBox text.

Was this helpful?

Comment: A little, but I feel maybe I am still not understanding. When trying to use ThisAddIn.Application or Excel.Application there are no options to reference my user control in my custom task pane.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example? i feel i don't follow your question.

Comment: I added some actual code to help. Thank you in advance for taking the time to take a look :)

Comment: You should be able to access the control via the private member. do you get an exception? it is not out of scope as far as i see it

Comment: There are no exceptions. Intellisense just comes up with the normal properties for all user forms, I'm assuming. I'm unable to just write myUserCtrl.nameOfTextBox.Value. Should I be placing this eventhandler in the code with my userForm and not in the ThisAddIn.cs?

Comment: The best practice is to register a public function callback to the AddIn event handler - so within the function callback, you'll have full access to the custom control components. simply move `ThisAddIn_SheetSelectionChange` member to a public state on your `userCtrl` class and register it to the ` Application.SheetSelectionChange` event

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel like you've set me on the right track and there are issues I need to work out on my part. I get the exception "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'."

Comment: I would appreciate if you'll mark my answer as helpful (click the vi sign), thanks.